# action word for ruse?

Tags: word-choice

Ruse meaning: an action intended to deceive someone; a trick.

Can I use rusing?

Example:
I was rusing back there so you could make a clean getaway.

Comment: Ruse is a noun, not a verb: 
a trick, stratagem, or artifice: He used a ruse to get past the sentry.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ruse

Answer (score 3):

No. The idiomatic way would be to say

I was *playing a ruse*

Or better: *I was causing a diversion*

Alternative: *I created a smokescreen back there*

Answer (score 0):

[**beguile**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/beguile): *verb* 
Charm or enchant (someone), often in a deceptive way.

[**dupe**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dupe): *verb* Deceive; trick.

Source: Oxford Living Dictionaries: English.

Comment: "I was beguiling back there?"

Comment: Though "Beguiling" is an adjective form of beguile, it can also be used as a verb. For example:-(1) "It's music that bypasses the brain entirely, beguiling the soul with its ceaselessly inventive mercurial forms conjured literally out of the air."(2) Then this ebony bird beguiling my sad fancy into smiling, By the grave and stern decorum of the countenance it wore. look for more here:http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/beguiling

Comment: I know it can be used but it does not work in OP's example.

Comment: If "beguiling " sounds awkward , which I'm not sure that it does, we could use "bluff" as another word.